# 100 percent java implementation in SDL Tridion

Tags: web8

Is it possible to have an implementation of Tridion Web 8 without any microsoft technology usage both ad CM as well as CD side(not even IIS).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm afraid that it's not.

Your Content Delivery side can be 100% Linux & Java based, and you **could** write your own, custom Content Management editorial interface in Java to talk to SDL Web via the Core Service. However, the underlying Content Management (CM) engine is based on Microsoft technologies and uses, for example, Window Services (e.g. For publishing) and IIS (e.g. For the web services, such as the Core Service API).

SDL Web also supports a small number of non-Microsoft SQL Server databases (e.g. Oracle, RDS) both on the Content Manager (CM) and Content Delivery (CD) sides.

Hope this helps. Please update your question if you need any more specifics.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, For one of the project evaluation we have a constraint that we cannot use any microsoft technology and hence wanted to confirm if that is possible

Comment: What about hosting the CM outside the organization (cloud?) and keeping all the presentation/content delivery/content deployment in-house?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to have SDL Web Cloud and you would also have following advantages:

1. No organizational restriction on infrastructure as that would be managed by SDL
2. You will always be with the latest version as SDL Web Cloud is version-less
3. You can choose to have CMS on SDL Web Cloud while having your applications in your own environment - or you can even choose to have SDL Web Cloud used as headless CMS.

Comment: Thanks Pankaj, but there are few internal application which actually creates component in CMS. Is it possible to do the same with SDL web Cloud?